# Compare current hour with period of time

Tags: php, timestamp

I want to compare if the current hour is between the interval 7 PM to 1 AM
for example I want to do

```
if(time() > strtotime('7PM') && time()< strtotime('1AM'))
{
   echo "is between 7PM-1AM"
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: "1AM" will give you a point in time at the beginning of **today**, "7PM" at the evening of **today**. PHP doesn't automagically know that you mean "1AM tomorrow"!

Comment: guys, its not a code, thats what I wanted to do logically,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@deceze's comment above explains your problem. Here's an example that specifies 1AM the next day:

```
$now    = new DateTime();
$start  = new DateTime('7PM');
$finish = new DateTime('tomorrow 1AM');
if($now > $start && $now < $finish)
{
   echo "is between 7PM-1AM";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working, what if I want the interval between 7PM - 12AM(next day) ?
Thanks :)

Comment: ... *"I think there would be too much shenanigans to actually get anything done. lol"* @JohnConde True, yet all work and no play, makes for a boring day ;-) --- seems like the user's been deleted. I wonder when we'll be seeing that one again.

Comment: @JohnConde Some just don't let up, or they're looking for attention. I'd say, let 'em go buy a dog or somethin'